# How to recursive copy files from a list of files in a text file using a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

Parent folder: Root
Subfolder1: Has 12000 files i.e. subfolder1\885.txt
Subfolder2: Has 15000 files i.e. subfolder2\882.txt

Source file list `names.ext` contains 500 different names:

```
882.txt
550.txt
990.txt
300.txt
```

How to get my `FOR` loop to read the first line of names.ext, search for that file, copy it when found, read second line of names.ext and repeat.

```
@ECHO ON
SET RootDir=E:\Source
SET CopyDir=E:\Destination
IF NOT EXIST "%CopyDir%" MD "%CopyDir%"

SET CopyFname=882.txt '(Need to cater more file names rather than one such as 882.txt, 992.txt, 555.txt etc)'

FOR /D %%A IN ("%RootDir%\*") DO FOR %%B IN ("%%~A\%CopyFname%") DO ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%%~B" "%CopyDir%\"
GOTO EOF
```

Comment: I can't help but think PowerShell would be the easier option for this.  E.g. a simple starter to get going - https://pastebin.com/LnY0sNEg

Comment: How was names.ext made? Is it the oldest files? The newest files? The largest files? The smallest files? The files less than 14 days old? The file greater than 14 days old? The files without the archive attribute set? ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@ECHO OFF

SET "_RootDir=E:\Source"
SET "_CopyDir=E:\Destination\"
SET "_LstFile=E:\Source\Listnames.log"

TITLE <NUL & TITLE %~nx0 && 2>nul >nul MKdir "%_CopyDir%"

FOR /F Tokens^=*Delims^= %%# IN ('type "%_LSTFILE%"')DO (
FOR /F Tokens^=*Delims^= %%I IN ('^<con: "%__APPDIR__%WHERE.exe" /R "%_ROOTDIR%" "%%~#"
')DO "%__APPDIR__%XCopy.exe" /Y /F /V "%%~I" "%_CopyDir%"|"%__APPDIR__%FINDSTR.EXE" /V ")")
```

1. To read one (file) line by line and get the name of the file you are looking for in a root folder and its subfolders:

```py
FOR /F Tokens^=*Delims^= %%# IN ('type "%_LSTFILE%"')DO....
```

2. To effectively search for this file listed on the current line read in the previous loop, use `%%~#` as an argument passed to the `where` command along with the flag that it is used to search recursively and in your `%_RootDir%` folder:

```py
..')DO FOR /F Tokens^=*Delims^= %%I IN ('"%__APPDIR__%WHERE.exe" /R %_ROOTDIR% "%%~#"
```

3. Use the `For /F + WHERE /T` loop output as an argument to your `XCOPY`, thus copying the found file (where found) to its destination folder "%_CopyDir%\":

```py
..')do XCOPY /Y /F /V "%%~i" "%_CopyDir%\"
```

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[Where](https://www.petri.com/using-where-exe)**

  [√] **[XCopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)**

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

Comment: The code is working great. Only one more thing if same filename exists in subfolder can it be renamed as 855(1).txt 855(2).txt

Comment: @AsadAliHussaini this will need another question, add this task to check if file exist in target directory, count files there and add properly number in (x), is more complicate that add a fill lines code in this present question.  SO, add another, i've can provide this task, with more time..

Comment: Thanks again. You saved my job. I will post another question in a while.

Comment: @AsadAliHussaini thank you too for test, is nice to know that works, am sorry my limited English, and let me know about new question...